# Redirect from a partial view to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I’m receiving and error when I try to redirect from a partial view to a view

> The view or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.“

Partial View

```
 Html.RenderAction("RenderApplicant", " Application ");
```

Controller Application

```
public ActionResult RenderApplicant()
    {
        return View("applicant", null);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a view named `applicant.cshtml` (and show the full details of the error mesage)

Comment: Yes I have view applicant.cshtml within the view folder

Comment: And what do your mean _redirect_? Using `Html.RenderAction()` renders the partial view within your main view - it does not redirect.

Comment: Error : The view ‘applicant’ or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

Comment: Are you allowed to go from a partial view to a view?

Comment: You have to include the full message - i.e. the locations (in the question). And what do you mean _go from a partial view to a view_?

Comment: I read somewhere that you should RenderAction to a Index controller and then return the view – sorry I’m new to MVC, still learning...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151486/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tom).